The oauth state was missing or invalid. in asp.net web api when trying to implament google outh
i am trying to implement google auth and i seem to missunderstand the auth flow , i looked through every sub and post allready and tried all the fixes there but nothing seems to work , i dont exectly understand how the controller is supposed to be structured. the error i keep getting is The oauth state was missing or invalid. (also using react for front end). these are the middlewares . added all the relevent code sorry for the amount of (https://i.sstatic.net/oJWtuRnA.png)
using Hangfire;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using RestaurantManagement.API.Data;
using RestaurantManagement.API.Interfaces;
using RestaurantManagement.API.Services;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using RestaurantManagement.API.Models;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        // Configure System.Text.Json options
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null; // Preserve capitalization
    });


// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddLogging();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IWeekService,WeekService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IShiftService, ShiftService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IEmployeeService, EmployeeService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IJobService, JobService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IConfigService, ConfigService>();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("RestaurantManagementAPIContext"))
);

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowReactFrontend", builder =>
    {
        builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5173", "https://localhost:5173", "https://localhost:7075") //
               .AllowAnyHeader()
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowCredentials(); 
    });
});

builder.Services.AddIdentity<Employee, IdentityRole>(options => {
    
})
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

// Add session
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
 .AddCookie(options =>
 {
     options.Cookie.Name = "ResturantManagmentApi.Cookie"; 
     options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1); 
     options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
     options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always ;

 })
.AddGoogle(options =>
{
    options.ClientId = "ClintId";
    options.ClientSecret = "ClientSecret";

});



builder.Services.AddHangfire((sp, config) =>
{
    var connectionString = sp.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>().GetConnectionString("RestaurantManagementAPIContext");
    config.UseSqlServerStorage(connectionString);
});
builder.Services.AddHangfireServer();

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Your API", Version = "v1" });

    // Add support for authentication
    c.AddSecurityDefinition("cookie", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
        In = ParameterLocation.Cookie,
        Name = ".AspNetCore.Cookies" // This should match your cookie name
    });

    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference { Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "cookie" }
            },
            new string[] { }
        }
    });
});


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseSession();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("AllowReactFrontend");
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire");

//run recurring services
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var jobService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IJobService>();
    jobService.RunWeekClosingRecurringJob();
    jobService.RunWeekFinalizingRecurringJob();
}

app.Run();

tried removing/adding the callbackpath, tried using token id sent from front end and validate that(had cors issues all the time) , serched for best practices and got the the current code (yes alot of it is gpt as i couldnt manage on my own but gpt also couldnt so hoping someone would be able to help.
expectation: logging in with google and staying authenticated for an x period of time.

Could you post the whole program.cs code?

@QiangFu Yes i updated the post

This is a really strange structure for me. You seems want to combine the default "asp.net core individual identity" with "google auth provider" . Similar to this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-8.0. But this is not for webapi, but for MVC.

@QiangFu Then what would be a better approach to do it in web app? Basically I want to use identity to manage all my users, but for register/login ATM we only want to implement google, I seem to have mixed up a few things but can't figure it out. For now we managed another approach of front sending a tokenid after it auths with google and the back just sends back user info , but I don't know how to manage that so the user is authenticated and can use [authrize] routes

I don't think the built in AddGoogle work for this. Myabe you could implement oauth2 with google independently. Then if the google auth success,  generate corresponding local cookie scheme accordingly.

@QiangFu So a flow like this :  1.keep the auth on the front side  2.send the token ID to the back 3.validate it with google 4. Generate a cookie and send to front 5. Front include cookie with each request. With this approach how do I make the [authorize] annotation only work when the cookie is recived
